# Solution of nonlinear waves( breathers)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, mathematica, hyperbolic-functions

The sine-Gordon equation is known as $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \sin u = 0,$$

Can you please derive the [equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breather)  which is known as breather equation and obtained by collitsion of two solitions $$u = 4 \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-\omega^2}\;\cos(\omega t)}{\omega\;\cosh(\sqrt{1-\omega^2}\; x)}\right).$$

Comment: Would you mind posting the relevant background material in LaTeX? I can't view the Google Book you posted.

Comment: Okay. Thanks, I'm doing it.